# dbms_job not executing jobs at regular interval inside trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

```
Create or replace TRIGGER AFT_INSERT_TMP_TBL
AFTER INSERT ON TMP_TBL
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 

V_SQL   VARCHAR2(1000);
A_NAME  VARCHAR2(100);
l_jobno NUMBER;
BEGIN
A_NAME:='ANY_NAME';

dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                 'myProc',
                 sysdate + interval '2' minute,
                 'sysdate + interval ''2'' minute' );
END AFT_INSERT_TMP_TBL;
```

I have a trigger which creates a `dbms_job` and the job will run for every two minutes after then. The problem I am getting is the trigger executes multiple times and the job sits in the queue as seen in `USER_JOBS` and never gets executed. I cannot write `commit` inside the trigger, so how to get this job up and running in every two minutes.

Comment: Do other jobs run? Just wondering if this is a wider question about making jobs run. Regarding the `commit`, presumably whatever inserts the row commits it at some point.

Comment: If you want the job to run even if the trigger's calling statement is rolled back, you *could* make the trigger use an autonomous transaction - but that's usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is doing exactly the right thing - it isn't triggering the jobs until the row is committed.

What do you want to happen in this case?

```
insert into tmp_tbl (col1) values ('Wrong value');
rollback;
```

I'd guess you wouldn't want any jobs to be triggered?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a procedure that submits the job. Then the trigger can call the procedure.